# Why I can't use an imported component inside a functional component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. For the code readability, instead of in-line styled button, I want to write it as a separate class component. I created a customed button 'addImageButton'and imported it to another .js file. It doesn't render the customer button when I try to use it within a functional component. How can I make the functional component be able to use the imported button? Thanks!

```
//addImageButton.js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class addImageButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          style={{
            borderStyle: "dotted",
            borderRadius: 1,
          }}
        >
          <span>Add Image</span>
          <span>Optional</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default addImageButton;

//AddNewTaskButton.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Modal from "react-modal";
**import addImageButton from "../addImageButton";**
class AddNewTaskButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false,
    };
    this.setShow = this.setShow.bind(this);
    this.closeShow = this.closeShow.bind(this);
    this.addTaskModal = this.addTaskModal.bind(this);
  }
  setShow() {
    this.setState({
      show: true,
    });
  }
  closeShow() {
    this.setState({
      show: false,
    });
  }

  addTaskModal = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.show}
          onRequestClose={() => this.closeShow()}
        >
        **<addImageButton />**

        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setShow()}>
          <img src={addIcon} alt={text}></img>;
          <span>text</span>
        </button>
        <this.addTaskModal className="modal" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddNewTaskButton;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier way would be to just use functional components. Also, react components should be upper case, like so:

```
export default function AddImageButton() {
  return (
  <div>...</div>
 )
}
```

create a different component for Modal

```
import Modal from './Modal'
import AddImageButton from './AddImageButton'

function AddTaskModal() {
  return (
   <div>
    <Modal> <AddImageButton/> </Modal>
   </div>
  )
}
```

then

```
import AddTaskModal from './AddTaskModal'

function AddNewTaskButton() {
  return (
   <div>
    <AddTaskModal/>
   </div>
  )
}
```

I don't know your file directories, so I just put randomly.

as for your question, try to make the AddImageButton as a class and see if it renders then. If it doesn't it might be due to something else. Do you get errors? Also maybe create the AddTaskModal class separately and render it out as a component. Maybe that'll help

Comment: I tried to write the modal as a separate component but it failed to change the state that controls opening/closing even though I passed down the setState() as a prop of the modal component. Do you mind giving more content regarding this part? Thanks!!!!!!!!

Comment: I think it would be easier to maintain if you used a react context. if you are using class components, take a read the docs here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consuming-multiple-contexts

else, I recommend switching to functional components if that's an option, then you can pass state via useContext() hook which is very helpful. I tend to avoid throwing props around. Good luck!

Comment: Also, please edit your question if you changed something! maybe others can also see what you did and help ^^